# svn equivalent to hg in

Tags: svn, mercurial

Where I used to work, we version-controlled with Mercurial.  I have a new job and we use Subversion there.  I'm new to Subversion.

I find myself wanting to know what has been checked in since my checkout on the remote repo.  In Mercurial, I'd use *hg in*.  This would show me the set of changesets available remotely but not in my local repo.  How do I do such a thing in Subversion?  That is, how to I find what changes have been done since my last co/update?

From my reading, it looks like *svn update* is used a lot, but I don't want my working copy to be modified with who knows what.  I want to see what's out there (if anything) before doing a pull.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to see the actual commit summaries as part of this, and for that you can use `svn log`.

Specifically, you can use `svn log -r HEAD:BASE` to see all commits up to and including your latest update, starting with the latest revision. (To see the newest revision last, swap HEAD and BASE.)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but just to make sure I'm following you: are you saying that svn log will query the server and retrieve the latest changeset information?  That is, even the information following my last update?  From my Mercurial experience, I'm used to log giving information about my local database only.  If you affirm that my understanding of your "up to and including your latest update" statement is accurate, then you'll get my vote and I'll accept this as my answer.

Comment: @firebush: That is indeed correct; svn log checks commits on the server, not the client.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the following command (from [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re26.html)):

```
svn status -u
```

or

```
svn status --show-updates
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. With Subversion you don't have a local repo. What you checkout is the working copy, not a repository.

When you update, you get the changes from the server (i.e. it's update+fetch), when you run commit you send the changes to the server (i.e. commit+push). It's not possible to accumulate change sets locally and then send them to the server. It all goes directly to the server or comes from the server.

If you find this antiquated, keep in mind that Subversion is older than Mercurial. Most people switch from Subversion to either git or Mercurial, not the other way around. (I see that you do this because you got a new employer.)